# How to write sql for this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table(a relationship) like

```
MyTab(ID1,ID2,IsMarked, data,....)
```

the sample data maybe looks like:

```
1,  1, 1, ...
1,  2, 0, ...
1,  3, 0, ...

2,  34, 1, ...

3,  4, 0, ...

4,  546, 0, ...
4,  8, 0, ...
```

Only one could be marked for each `ID1`.  I want to get data marked as `1` for all Entities `ID1`. If there is no marked record, get the first one or any one of them.

For above sample data, the result should be:

```
1,  1, 1, ...

2,  34, 1, ...

3,  4, 0, ...

4,  546, 0, ...
```

Union could be a solution, but is too long and may have bad performance. 
My idea is to sort the data by `ID1` and  `IsMarked` desc, the get the first 1 for each `ID1`, but how to write a `SQL` for this case?

Comment: *If there is no makred record, get the first one*, how are you ordering those rows?, how do you know which row is the first one?

Comment: Is it possible for the same ID1 to have multiple IsMarked set? E.g. can data look as 1,1,1... 1,2,1 ...

Answer (score 3):

For *Only one could be marked for each ID1* the following should work:

```
;with cte as (
    select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by ID1 order by IsMarked desc)
)
select *
from cte
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM MYTAB A
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(ID2) AS MAXID2, ID1
            FROM MYTAB
                WHERE ISMARKED=1
                    GROUP BY ID1
    ) B ON A.ID2=B.MAXID2 AND A.ID1=B.ID1
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(ID2) AS MAXID2, ID1
                FROM MYTAB
                    WHERE ISMARKED=0
                        GROUP BY ID1
        ) C ON A.ID2=C.MAXID2 AND A.ID1=C.ID1
            WHERE
                (B.ID1 IS NOT NULL)
                OR
                (B.ID1 IS NULL AND C.ID1 IS NOT NULL);
```